# Cutting a 2mm wide / 3mm deep groove

Tags: wood, cutting

How can I cut a groove between say 1.5mm to 2.5mm wide using the Dremel Cutting guide in the 565 kit? The cutting bit 561 is too wide at 3.2mm.

Comment: If Dremel doesn't make it, you might have to look for an aftermarket solution; either with some adapter or smaller cutting tool. You are just as likely to find this online as we are.

Comment: If you want an answer to the question, "how can I make a 2.5mm groove in wood", then [edit] the question and tell us how you intend to groove the material. It matters if you are grooving along a length, or really long pieces width-wise, etc. Maybe show a sketch of what you want, and let the hive-mind come up with solutions to the problem. Otherwise, this is a shopping question or maybe an X-Y question.

Comment: This sounds like you just need someone to help you find a 2mm 1/8" shank router bit.  This type of "shopping" question is considered off-topic so I'm going to vote to close it.  That said, there are plenty of places that you can get things like that.  Right off the cuff I'd suggest MicroMark or StewMac.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a "shopping" question

Comment: Two words: scratch stock. Your project will be done before a bit arrives, even with next-day delivery (if that's still a thing during the pandemic).

Answer (score 1):

Is cutting bit 561 the smallest that is made that you can chuck into your Dremel? Find a narrower bit - it might not be made by Dremel.

Try a hobby store - model railroading/RC aircraft, not woodworking. They'll have absolutely tiny bits, there's bound to be something that will do the trick. It may take multiple passes to get to your desired width/depth. You might have to buy a whole new <s>toy</s> er, tool to do it, but if you really need a groove that small, that may well be what it takes.

You could also probably do it with a hand saw. I believe some of the Japanese saws are pretty thin, with some searching you could probably find one that fits the bill.

If you're absolutely sold on using the Dremel and can't find a cutter small enough, you may just be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole world of CNC bits with 1/8" shanks that will work for this. Here's just one link:
https://www.ebay.com/str/CARBIDE-PLUS/DIAMETER-070-0799/_i.html?_storecat=50046017013
You can probably find individual bits on Amazon or visit Kyocera online. As mentioned you should specify what material you're working with for more relevant replies.